# Runtime parameter for code deploy releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When deploying new code to my Web App with Azure DevOps 'Releases' in the "Pipelines" section (NOT to be confused with the 'Pipelines' that build the code), is it possible to set a runtime parameter before the release starts deploying code?

I have a situation where I only want to delete my collection in my CosmosDB when I'm also planning to restore my database in SQL Server.  Currently, I have a 'Cosmos DB Collection Management' task in my Release pipeline that always deletes my collection, but as stated above, I only want to delete based on a certain condition.

I know I can create an identical release pipeline and just remove the 'CosmosDB delete collection' task, but I'd like to be working with a single release instead of multiple ones.

Comment: Any update about this issue?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to set up a custom condition for the task, it was located under the 'Control Options', then setting the 'Run this task' to custom conditions and then putting in the condition.  However, it doesn't seem like it's picking it up.  So I'll be creating a new question with the new issue considering that my original question was discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure out how to put in a custom condition.  For the CosmosDB Collection Management task, all I had to do was the following 2 things.

1. I need to create a 'release' variable 'CosmosSkip' so that when creating the release in Azure DevOps, I could set the variable to false or true and have the step skipped or not.
2. Under the 'Control Options', go to 'Run this task', set it to *custom conditions* and then put the expression in there <strike>(which was: eq('${{ variables.CosmosSkip }}', 'false') ; however, I believe the expression might be wrong and will need some tweaking)</strike>.  So the original boolean expression I was using was incorrect. What worked for me correctly was --> **eq(variables.CosmosSkip, 'False')**. The extra curly bracketsand dollar sign were not needed for this.

The documentation that helped me realize this was from the following MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a custom variable as a condition under ymal file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

You could use the following yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  ....

  test: 'true'

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job : A1
      steps:
      # your custom task
      - task: xxx 
     
      # your custom task
      - task: xxx

     

    - job: A2
      condition:  eq('$(test)', 'true')
      steps:
        # CosmosDB delete collection task
        - task: xxx
```

You could change the value of `test` to control that task.